# How can I automate my spider runs using scrapyd?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I know this probably seems ridiculous. I have given up on a windows scrapyd implementation and have set up a ubuntu machine and got everything working just great.  I ahve 3 projects each with their own spider.  I can run my spiders from the terminal using:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider2
```

Everything seems to work in the web UI as well with the scraped items from when I run the above code showing up in the correct places.

I want to run project 1 every day at 12:00am, project 2 every second day at 2:00am and project 3 every 2 weeks at  4:00am. Please help me to learn how to do this.

Is scrapyd even an appropriate solution for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduled Tasks seems to do the trick.  I have to say I'm left wondering if it was really worth the effort of setting up a ubuntu machine for the sole purpose of running scrapyd when I could have just scheduled the scrapy crawl commands with `schtasks` in windows.

Comment: but now I can enjoy the view from ubuntu  ahhh~~~